# confused by benchmark test among vultr and aws and digital ocean

Tags: amazon-web-services

There is a test over different cloud service provider
https://www.vultr.com/benchmarks/

it looks like the performance of digitalocean and vultr vps are better than aws cloud ec2

confused by the result.

your comment welcome

Answer (score 1):

We did an IOPS and throughput test recently with mongoperf of VULTR vs DigitalOcean vs Linode, because all three offer locally attached SSD drives. 
We were trying to find the best provider for hosting our MongoDB database. **VULTR came out on top!** Especially we got better performance results in New Jersey US datacenter, almost twice the speed of DO.

https://www.mywebtech.blog/vultr-digitalocean-linode-iops-performance-mongoperf/

Regarding AWS and Azure, as far as I know, the SSD storage they both offer is not locally attached, they also limit number of IOPS available depending on the size of your instance. Azure is the worst with max 300-500IOPS.

Answer (score 0):

I tested I/O Performance of AWS instance   & Vultr Server (1gb ram, 20GB SSD,1 core) and i found that vultr benchmark results was correct.

I used following command to test IO-

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=diskbench bs=1M count=1024 conv=fdatasync
```

For AWS server it was  **63.0 MB/s** and for vultr server it was **274 MB/s**  ,So without any doubt vultr`s hard-disk is much faster than aws.
AWS Claims that they are providing SSD with EBS , but it was slower than normal hard disk. :p .